# Load 3D objects in Unity from Firebase

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am currently developing an application wherein I need to load 3D objects in the camera directly from Firebase using script(during runtime). Is it possible to do this? I am currently loading my 3D scripts from the Resources folder with the code:

```
object1 = (GameObject)Resources.Load ("tabouret_2") as GameObject;
        var myObject = Instantiate (object1);
        myObject.transform.SetParent (parent.transform);
        myObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
        myObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (100f, 100f, 100f);
        myObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider> ();
        MoveObject uhm = myObject.AddComponent<MoveObject>() as MoveObject;
        myObject.gameObject.SetActive (true);
```

Is it also the same with retrieving 3D from firebase?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is, thank you for your question and contribution to stackoverflow! also: [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)... If you have any future questions! :)

Comment: sorry if i am not that good at asking, i am just new here at stack overflow. do you know how to do that?

Comment: No problem, just wanted to highlight that if you ask a question "can I do X?" here, you will likely not get any replies. The more detail around your issue and what you've tried already will get you help and replies! I've never worked with firebase before but I'm interested and I'm looking into your issue right now.

Comment: [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/unity/download-files) seems to be how you do it. There's unity specific documentation in the Firebase docs

Comment: Firebase developer here.  Indeed Fredrik's link to Firebase Storage is the way this should be done.  You can actually store assets in Firebase and then get the "Download Url".  Once you have the download url, you can use unity's built in libraries such as WWW or UnityWebRequest to download directly into a usable asset.